# jQuery UI Dialog Gets Messed Up

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I have several dialog boxes in a website I built for a client. **When two dialogs are open at the same time, things eventually get messed up**. The dialog seems to be looking good the first time it shows up. But then when the user closes the dialog **(the one on top)** and opens it again, it gets messed up. (check the images)

What I'm basically doing is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#someDiv").dialog({
      //options
   });

   $("#someButton").click(function() {
      $("#someDiv").dialog('open');
   });

   $("#closeButton").click(function() {
      $("#someDiv").dialog('close');
   });
});
```

That's basically the flow of how I open and close the dialogs. Am I doing anything wrong?

When the user opens the dialog for the first time: http://i43.tinypic.com/2dt9fk7.png

When the user opens the dialog again: http://i40.tinypic.com/v6sqq9.png

Comment: Nope, nothing wrong in that code. Probably a CSS issue.

Comment: @cambraca: But why does it work the first time and gets messed up the second time? This doesn't make any sense to me... :/

Comment: @cambraca: Apparently I was wrong, I described the issue incorrectly. I will send you a link when I set things up in my test environment to make it easy to re-produce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I mostly agree with cambraca; however, here's another thought to add to the "It's CSS" point:

When the dialog gets closed, jQuery UI doesn't seem to move it back to its original place in the DOM tree. It seems to get moved to just before the `</body>` closing tag. So for consistency, change your markup so that it STARTS there as well, thereby avoiding possible CSS style inheritance issues.